# legacy jsp on tomcat 6, jasper compiler error on the generated sources

Tags: jsp, tomcat, centos

I'm migrating a `spring` mvc application which contains a lots of java code in jsp files and when I run it on `tomcat 6.0.24` under `CentOS 5.x`, I'm getting jsp compilation errors. I'm developping under Windows XP and the same application runs very well on tomcat `6.0.34` and `jetty 8.`

I tried to play with compilerSourceVM and compilerTargetVM with no success.

**catalina.out**

```
An error occurred at line: 18 in the generated java file
The type Collection is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends E>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
  at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:589)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:215)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$0(TagFileProcessor.java:564)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:686)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:703)
```

Comment: What version of Java are you running Tomcat with? Are there any old versions also installed?

Comment: The latest version of JDK 6.x is installed on the server. I checked via tomcat manager that tomcat run with it. But, the JDK IcedTea is also installed on the server but is not the default java.